# two axios requests, one response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

it appears the api im using breaks a list of 250 assets into multiple pages. im trying to call numerous pages to be listed in an ant design table

```js
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [],
        loading: true
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.all([
      axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=1&sparkline=true&price_change_percentage=24hr'),
      axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=2&sparkline=true&price_change_percentage=24hr')
    ])
    .then(axios.spread((res => {
      const data = res.data;
      this.setState({ data, loading: false })
  })))
}

  render() {

    const { data } = this.state;

    const tableData = data.map(row => ({
      Rank: row.market_cap_rank,
      Symbol: row.symbol,
      Name: row.name,
      Price: row.current_price,
      marketCap: row.market_cap,
      priceChange: row.price_change_percentage_24h,
      sparkline: row.sparkline_in_7d.price
    }))

    const columns = [{
      title: 'Rank',
      dataIndex: 'Rank',
      key: 'market_cap_rank',
    }, {
      title: 'Symbol',
      dataIndex: 'Symbol',
      key: 'symbol',
      render: (value) => {
        return <span>{value.toUpperCase()}</span>;
      },
    }, {
      title: 'Name',
      dataIndex: 'Name',
      key: 'name',
    }, {
      title: 'Price',
      dataIndex: 'Price',
      key: 'current_price',
      render: (value) => {
        return <span>$<b>{value.toFixed(2)}</b></span>;
      },
    }, {
      title: 'Market Cap',
      dataIndex: 'marketCap',
      key: 'market_cap',
      render: (value) => {
        return`$${value}`.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
      },
...

    <Table 
      pagination="false"
      loading={this.state.loading} 
      dataSource={tableData} 
      columns={columns} 
      size="small"
    />
```

this works, but only displays the first page and not the second *as well*

sorry for the silly question, maybe someone can take a moment to assist me as this question probably stems from a lack of general understanding. it's sure nice to hear from other people on here! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update your `componentDidMount` like below

```
axios.all([
      axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=1&sparkline=true&price_change_percentage=24hr'),
      axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=2&sparkline=true&price_change_percentage=24hr')
    ])
    .then(resArr =>{
      const data = [];
      resArr.map(res=> data.push(...res.data));
      this.setState({ data, loading: false });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the function you pass to axios.spread receives the result of the requests in two different arguments.

Like in the example from the [axios doc](https://github.com/axios/axios#example)

```
function getUserAccount() {
  return axios.get('/user/12345');
}

function getUserPermissions() {
  return axios.get('/user/12345/permissions');
}

axios.all([getUserAccount(), getUserPermissions()])
  .then(axios.spread(function (acct, perms) {
    // Both requests are now complete
  }));
```

your axios.spread will receive separately the two pages :

You can then concatenate the two pages to have your data

```
axios
  .all([
    axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=1&sparkline=true&price_change_percentage=24hr'),
    axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=2&sparkline=true&price_change_percentage=24hr')
    ])
  .then(axios.spread(((page1, page2) => {
    const data = [...page1.data, ...page2.data];
    this.setState({ data, loading: false })
  })))
```

If you want to have more than a determinate number of pages you can make use of rest operator and flatten the array using spread and concat

```
axios
  .all(arrayOfLinks)
  .then(axios.spread(((...pages) => { // use rest operator to get an array of pages containing your data
    const data = [].concat(...pages.data); // use spread operator in a concat to flatten your arrays of data
    this.setState({ data, loading: false })
  })))
```